# Prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is not isometric to any proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

The question is in the title. I can show easily that $\mathbb{R}$ is not isometric to any closed interval $[a,b]$ in $\mathbb{R}$, but I am struggling to show it for any arbitrary subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f : \mathbb R\to X$ be isometric. Note that $|f(x) - f(0)| = |x|$ implies $f(x) = f(0) + x$ or $f(x) = f(0)-x$. Assume $a\notin X$. Then $f(a-f(0)) = 2f(0)-a$ (because otherwise $f(a-f(0)) = a$ and hence $a\in X$) and $f(f(0)-a) = 2f(0)-a$. So, since $f$ is injective, $a-f(0) = f(0) - a$, i.e., $f(0) = a$, thus $a\in X$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. If $x$ is not in image of $f\,,$ then by the intermediate value theorem either $x$ is a lower bound or an upper bound for $f\,;$ without loss of generality a lower bound. So $f$ is bounded from below, so can $f$ be an isometry?

Comment: Can you explain your proof a bit thoroughly? What do you mean by "by IVT?" and why do we wish to know whether or not if $x$ is in the image of $f$?

Answer (score 0):

if $X$ is any proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then there is $a\in \mathbb{R}\backslash X $. Since $ \mathbb{R}$ is connected either $x\in X \Rightarrow x < a$ or $x\in X \Rightarrow x > a$ is always true. So $X$ either has a supremum or infimum. Can you finish the reasoning from here?

Comment: $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ does neither have infimum nor supremum.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp $\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$ is not connected. This case was excluded right at the beginning.